Match object with array key to exact values using jq
Match first object which has an array that contains exactly same values (it's should always be length of 2)
Example:
[
  { "id": 242, "size": [500, 500] },
  { "id": 234, "size": [500, 1920] },
  { "id": 168, "size": [234, 1080] },
  { "id": 315, "size": [1080, 1920] },
  { "id": 366, "size": [1920, 1080] },
  { "id": 367, "size": [1920, 1080] }
]

width=1920
height=1080

# Should match:
# { id: 366, size: [1920, 1080] }

# Then extract id (easy, got this part)


My best attempt was to use contains, but it doesn't seems contains can take more than 1 argument:
echo $json | jq -r ".[] | select( [ .size[] | contains($width) ] | any ) | .id"


Why remove "bash" tag?

I don't see how it's related to bash, it seems just a JQ problem

Well thank you now all solutions ignore bash part and don't use $width and $height vars...

Construct the array, compare it to .size, and use first to only get the first match:
jq --argjson width 1920 --argjson height 1080 '
  first(.[] | select(.size == [$width, $height]).id)
'

Demo
jq --argjson size '[1920, 1080]' '
  first(.[] | select(.size == $size).id)
'

Demo
Output:
366


Thank you! Modified --argjson to --argjson size "[$width, $height]" for my use case because I use bash which was removed from tags.

If in Bash you happened to have stored the values in an array, say size=(1920 1080), you could also consider … | jq 'first(.[] | select(.size == $ARGS.positional).id)' --jsonargs "${size[@]}".
